# font display error in Vscode when using markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use a dark theme in my VSCode. However, when I review the UI of a plugin or open a markdown file, the font is displayed in dark, making it hard for me to distinguish. It's worth noting that when I change my theme (even if I just reload the current theme), the font is correctly displayed.
[Screenshot of JSON Addon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlJ2B.png)
[Screenshot of VS Code Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIder.png)

They don't work. I wonder if there is someone who has encountered the same error? I need your help...

1. Unable all the plugins.
2. Reinstall the VScode.

Both approaches didn't work.

a more comprehensive
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNuNe.gif)

Comment: Does this happen for all dark themes?

Comment: Related information is shown below:                                                              
Version: 1.82.2 (user setup)
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

Comment: This actually happen for all dark theme. Besides, I have tried to disable all the extensions (as you suggested), but it doesn't work. Maybe it is not caused by the extensions I think...

Comment: what's the markdown editor extension that you're using? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zaaack.markdown-editor ? if so, do any of the [existing open issue tickets](https://github.com/zaaack/vscode-markdown-editor/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+dark) fit your issue?

Comment: Thank you for being so patient. It's so nice of you. I use the Office viewer(https://github.com/cweijan/vscode-office). However, I think it may not be caused by the markdown editor extension. Even though I have disabled all the extensions, the font is still incorrectly displayed in light mode. I guess it may be caused by some corrupt CSS file in Vscode? Maybe I need to thoroughly uninstall Vscode and then install it again to handle this... For now, I can only switch the theme to temporarily fix it. Anywhere, really grateful for your help~A

Comment: have you made any changes to your `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting?

Comment: definitely no. Maybe my descriptions before are not so clear. Now I have posted a GIF to show the problem. See the problem description. It's really weird.